# Selling and distributing my Software

Tags: software

Am a developer and likes to develop my own personal software. I use it for a few months and make some improvements it as i go along. I would like to know on what safe and secure online site can i sell my software.

I normally write desktop applications like converting Excel files to Csv, splitting text files into smaller files, Excel Add-ins and sales forecasting tools.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

first of all its a tricky question to answer with this little information. It depends greatly on the Topic of your Software. But in most cases you should start in Forums of your Topic to generate some Clients/Person who want to use your Software. In the meantime an own Website to distribute the Software and what benefit you get from it would also be a good idea in my opinion.

If you just want to put the software somewhere to get some Money, just try to search for "Platform for selling Software". You will get many results.

I will not recommend you any directly Website because it differs from what you prefer or which Topic your software is about.

In order to help you better, please provide more Information about the Software and which Clients you want to approach.